# Change buttons relief on click using tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I want to create buttons labelled with names from a list. When you click on a button its relief shall change from groove to sunken. There is one condition, only one button is allowed to be sunken. Thus, when you click on a button while another one is already sunken, the sunken one has to go back to groove.
[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLzbq.png)

I was able to put my idea into action and coded the whole thing. However, I'm wondering if there might be a better way to implement it. What is your opinion? Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

class ButtonSunken:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tags = ('A','B','C','D','E','F')
        self.buttons = []
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.create_buttons()
        self.win.mainloop()

    def create_buttons(self):
        for j,i in enumerate(self.tags): 
            self.buttons.append(tk.Button(self.win, text = i))
            self.buttons[-1].grid(column=0, row=j)
            ho_general = partial(self.button_pressed, self.buttons[-1])
            self.buttons[-1].configure(command = ho_general)

    def button_pressed(self, button):
        try: # first time active_button does not exist yet
            self.active_button.configure(relief = 'groove')
        except:
            pass
        button.configure(relief = 'sunken')
        self.active_button = button       

t_object = ButtonSunken()
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is pretty much good, just that it can be done without using any *special* functions. In my code, I just store the index of the current active button and set its relief to `groove` whenever the next button is pressed whose relief is in turn changed to `sunken`. Have a look at the code.

```
import tkinter as tk

class ButtonSunken:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tags = ('A','B','C','D','E','F')
        self.buttons = []
        self.active = None
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.create_buttons()
        self.win.mainloop()

    def create_buttons(self):
        for j,i in enumerate(self.tags): 
            self.buttons.append(tk.Button(self.win, text=i, command=lambda x=j: self.button_pressed(x)))
            self.buttons[-1].grid(column=0, row=j)

    def button_pressed(self, idx):
        if self.active is not None:
            self.buttons[self.active].configure(relief='groove')
        self.buttons[idx].configure(relief='sunken')
        self.active = idx      

t_object = ButtonSunken()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I like your solution, it's much better/easier to hand over the index than the whole object. Up to now, I was a bit reluctant towards the Lambda function, however, I realize it's pretty useful.